# How to create custom post types in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to know the procedure of how to create custom post types with WordPress. I will be thankful if anyone help me with complete procedure of code and plugins. I will also be writing a blog post regarding this issue and I need help from top contributors of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Full code hear: http://cmsblogheart.wordpress.com/2014/03/07/wordpress-custom-post-type/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add code similar to this to your `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'your_custom_name',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Custom_names' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Custom_names' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

after it you can see a another option in your dashbooard left bar to add custom post.
[see more about Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require_once 'wp-load.php'; //path of wp-load.php

$name = 'my post';
$content = 'dummy Content here';
$featured_image = 'fullimage url.jpg'; //pass here full image url

$post_data = array(
    'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $name ),
    'post_content'  => $content,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_category' => array(1,2),
    'page_template' => ''
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data, $error_obj );

// for custom field
//add_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_date', 'Dec 5, 2018' ); // second parameter is your custom field name, 3rd parameter is value

generate_Featured_Image($featured_image, $post_id );

function generate_Featured_Image( $image_url, $post_id  ){
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
    $filename = basename($image_url);
    if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))
        $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    else
        $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    $res1= wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    $res2= set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
    echo 'post created...';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_custom_event() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Events', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Events', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Events' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Events' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Events' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Events' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Events' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Events' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Events' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No Events found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Events found in the Trash' ), 
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Events'
);

$args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Events',
    'public'        => true,
    'show_ui'        => true,
    'capability_type'  => 'post',
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array( 'title' , 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'page-attributes'),
    'has_archive'   => true,
);   

register_post_type( 'event', $args );   
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_event' );
```

Comment: A little bit of narrarive explaining what you did here would be really nice. At least a couple of code comments?

Answer (score 0):

```
## This is my full working code for creating custom post types ##
    function slide_init()
    {
        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => 'Slider',
            'singular_name'         => 'Slider',
            'menu_name'             => 'Slider',
            'name_admin_bar'        => 'Slider',
            'add_new'               => 'Add New Slider',
            'add_new_item'          => 'Add New Slider',
            'new_item'              => 'New Slider',
            'edit_item'             => 'Edit Slider',
            'view_item'             => 'View Slider',
            'all_items'             => 'All Slider Images',
            'search items'          => 'Search Slider',
            'parent_item_colon'     => 'Parent Slider',
            'not_found'             => 'No Slider Found',
            'not_found_in_trash'    => 'No Slider Found In Trash',
            );

        $args = array(
            'labels'                => $labels,
            'public'                => true,
            'publicaly_queryable'   => true,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_in_menu'          => true,
            'query_var'             => true,
            'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'Slider' ),
            'capability_type'       => 'post',
            'has_archive'           => true,
            'Hierarchical'          => false,
            'menu_position'         => null,
            'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-format-image',
            'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments','hierarchical','trackbacks','custom-fields','revisions','page-attributes'),
            'taxonomies'            =>array('category'),
            );

        register_post_type('Slider',$args);
        register_taxonomy('Slider_category','Slider',array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Category', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'slider-category')));
    }
    add_action('init','slide_init');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  /**  Meet the team custom post
```

You can use below WordPress script to create custom post type without any plugins */

```
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Team', 'Team', 'Team') ,
    'singular_name' => _x('Team', 'Team', 'rjis') ,
    'menu_name' => _x('Meet the Team', 'admin menu', 'rjis') ,
    'name_admin_bar' => _x('Team', 'add new on admin bar', 'rjis') ,
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Team', 'rjis') ,
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Team', 'rjis') ,
    'new_item' => __('New Team', 'rjis') ,
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Team', 'rjis') ,
    'view_item' => __('View Team', 'rjis') ,
    'all_items' => __('All Team Members', 'rjis') ,
    'search_items' => __('Search Team', 'rjis') ,
    'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Team:', 'rjis') ,
    'not_found' => __('No Team found.', 'rjis') ,
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Team found in Trash.', 'rjis')
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'description' => __('Description.', 'Meet the team') ,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'team'
    ) ,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => false,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array(
      'title',
      'editor',
      'author',
      'thumbnail',
      'excerpt'
    ) ,
    'menu_icon' => PLUGIN_URL . "images/team.png"
  );

 register_post_type('team', $args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Career word is Used for Given name for the PostType. You can make multiple post type just change Carrer Name.

```php
// career CUSTOM POST
$labels = array(
        'name' => 'career',
        'singular_name' => 'career',
        'add_new' => 'Add career',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New career',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit career',
        'new_item' => 'New career',
        'all_items' => 'All career',
        'view_item' => 'View career',
        'search_items' => 'Search career',
        'not_found' =>  'No career found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No career found in Trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'career'
    );
 $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'taxonomies' => array('career_cat'),
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
      'excerpt',
            'thumbnail',
  'custom-fields'
        )
    );
 register_post_type('career', $args);
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'career_Category',
        'singular_name' => 'career',
        'search_items' =>  'Search career_Categories',
        'all_items' => 'All career_Categories',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent career_Category',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent career_Category:',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit career_Category',
        'update_item' => 'Update career_Category',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New career_Category',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Category Name',
        'menu_name' => 'career_Categories'
    );
 $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => false,
        'capabilities' => array('manage_terms')
    );
    register_taxonomy('career_cat', array('career'), $args);
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('career'));
    set_post_thumbnail_size(100, 100);
```

Comment: There's something to fix in the format of the answer

Answer (score 0):

**"Portfolio" name Used for the PostType. You can Add portfolio-category remove and also add tags.**

```
    function ag_custom_post_type_init() {
    $ag_cust_post_argu = '';
    $ag_cust_post_argu = array(
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'  => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => true,
            'menu_position'      => null,
            'menu_icon'          => null,
            'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor' )
        );

     
  register_post_type(
    'portfolio', array(
      'labels' => array('name' => __( 'Portfolio' ), 'singular_name' => __( 'portfolio' ) ),
      'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug'       => 'portfolio',
            'with_front' => false,
        ),
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-site',
      'has_archive' => true,
      'parent' => 'Portfolio',
      'supports' => array('page-attributes','title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'excerpt'),
      $ag_cust_post_argu,
    )
  );  
  
}
add_action( 'init', 'ag_custom_post_type_init' );


function custom_post_type_tax_init_portfolio() {
    
    register_taxonomy(
        'portfolio-category',
        'portfolio',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Categories' ),
            
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug'       => 'portfolio-category',
                'with_front' => false,
                ),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_tax_init_portfolio' );

function custom_post_type_tag_init_portfolio() {
    
    register_taxonomy('portfolio_tag', 'portfolio', array(
    'hierarchical' => false, 
    'label' => "Tags", 
    'singular_name' => "tag", 
    'rewrite' => array(
                'slug'       => 'portfolio-tag',
                'with_front' => false,
                ), 
    'query_var' => true
    )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_tag_init_portfolio' );
```